# Compound of Geometric and Gamma distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Suppose $Y$ follows Geometric with $p$, and we know that conditional distribution of $X$ given on $Y=y$ is a $\Gamma(y,\lambda)$. What should be the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X = x>0$?

So my attempt here is simply do:
$$f_{X|Y}(x) = \frac 1 {\Gamma(y)} x^{y-1}e^{-\lambda x}$$
$$f_{Y}(y) = (1-p)^{(y-1)}p$$

such that,
$$f_{Y|X}(y) = f_{X|Y}(x)f_{Y}(y) = \frac {(1-p)^{(y-1)}p} {\Gamma(y)} x^{y-1}e^{-\lambda x}$$

But I am stuck here as I am not sure if we could continue on such expression. I have tried to make it looks like a Poisson but seems it makes it worse...

$$\frac {(1-p)^{(y-1)}p} {\Gamma(y)} x^{y-1}e^{-\lambda x} = \frac{(\lambda x- \lambda xp)^{(y-1)}}{(y-1)!} e^{-(\lambda x- \lambda xp)} p \lambda e^{-\lambda xp}$$

Or do we have a better approach to deal with such questions? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure about $f_{Y|X}(y) = f_{X|Y}(x)f_Y(y)$? It seems like $f_X(x)$ should also appear in that expression, as the right part equals $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ which is unequal (unless you have extra assumptions) to $f_{Y|X}(y)$.